# How can i call a web service without using KSOAP2 in Android?

Tags: android

I can call a webservice with KSOAP2 from android,now i want to know is it possible to call it without using KSOAP.If anyone knows the answer please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the webservice is available with a rest api I would use [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/).  I have some blog posts that show simple examples of using this library [here](http://broschb.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-and-google-app-engine.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SOAPActivity extends Activity {
     private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
        private final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx";
        private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertWeight";
        private final String METHOD_NAME = "ConvertWeight";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SoapObject soapObject=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        String weight = "700";
        String fromUnit = "Kilograms";
        String toUnit = "Grams";

        PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
        weightProp.setName("Weight");
        weightProp.setValue(weight);
        weightProp.setType(double.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(weightProp);

        PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
        fromProp.setName("FromUnit");
        fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
        fromProp.setType(String.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(fromProp);

        PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
        toProp.setName("ToUnit");
        toProp.setValue(toUnit);
        toProp.setType(String.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(toProp);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(weight+" "+fromUnit+" equal "+response.toString()+ " "+toUnit);
            setContentView(tv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

This is simple code for SOAP web service,