# connecting PHP webservices with Android

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am developing the android application. which is going to update the content from android to the web(php webservice). Can anyone give me the sample code for my reference.

Comment: You want to do what? Post data from android to the webservice or update data from the webservice to display in android?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of questions already on StackOverflow regarding calling webservices from Android.  Try looking at those.

For example:

[How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

[How can i call a web service without using KSOAP2 in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264207/how-can-i-call-a-web-service-without-using-ksoap2-in-android)

FYI, there should be no difference between a PHP webservice and a webservice written in any other language from the client's (Android's) point of view.

Comment: @Jcaruso PHP is a programming language, SOAP is a communication protocol. You can create SOAP web services in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I made a tutorial about this you can download the sample as well

[Part 1](http://guruparang.blogspot.com/2012/11/connect-android-and-mysql-via-php.html)
[Part 2](http://guruparang.blogspot.com/2012/12/connect-android-and-mysql-via-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way is to use `Sockets`. :)
if there are rest service you can use internal apache library - `DefaultClient`...

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/) was useful to me in using Android as a REST client. It shows how to use the Android libraries, without external dependencies, to perform basic GET/POST, etc.

Definitely search around if you need more information. There's plenty of resources on the issue.